# How to set the system property kie.maven.settings.custom

Tags: java, system, drools, kie

I found something here: [Setting KieContainer kie.maven.settings.custom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42446989/setting-kiecontainer-kie-maven-settings-custom) but I don't think it answers my question. I just want to know whether a simple `System.setProperty()` in Java would do the trick or do I need to do something else?

Comment: You haven't actually told us what you want to do, only that a different question doesn't apply to your issue. It's not a lot to go on.

Comment: Well it's in the title of the question: "How to set the system property kie.maven.settings.custom"

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set this option at code level then you can do it like as:

```
final String MVN_SETTING = "/home/user/settings.xml";
//...
System.setProperty("kie.maven.settings.custom", MVN_SETTING);
```

You can pass this option while starting server or while running client as well, like as:

```
-Dkie.maven.settings.custom=/home/user/settings.xml
```